# Update dictionary if in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm running through an excel file reading line by line to create dictionaries and append them to a list, so I have a list like:

```
myList = []
```

and a dictionary in this format:

```
dictionary = {'name': 'John', 'code': 'code1', 'date': [123,456]}
```

so I do this: `myList.append(dictionary)`, so far so good. Now I'll go into the next line where I have a pretty similar dictionary:

```
dictionary_two = {'name': 'John', 'code': 'code1', 'date': [789]}
```

I'd like to check if I already have a dictionary with `'name' = 'John'` in `myList` so I check it with this function:

```
def checkGuy(dude_name):
  return any(d['name'] == dude_name for d in myList)
```

Currently I'm writing this function to add the guys to the list:

```
def addGuy(row_info):
        if not checkGuy(row_info[1]):
            myList.append({'name':row_info[1],'code':row_info[0],'date':[row_info[2]]})
        else:
            #HELP HERE
```

in this else I'd like to `dict.update(updated_dict)` but I don't know how to get the dictionary here.

Could someone help so `dictionary` appends the values of `dictionary_two`?

Comment: Why don't you just make `myList` a dictionary, whose keys are the names?

Comment: You could have `checkGuy` return the matching element, rather than just a boolean. If it returns a dictionary, you update it, otherwise you append the new dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar Because there are more names and I guess it would be more organized with a list of dictionaries. I also thought of making the dictionary format a class but I don't feel comfortable enough to be dealing with objects at this point. Edit: That's actually not a bad idea...

Comment: Here's a resource [link](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/66516-add-an-entry-to-a-dictionary-unless-the-entry-is-a/)

Comment: is name the only key you will search with?

Comment: @Will at the moment yes, It's the only one I can assure to be unique.

Comment: If it is the @Barmar 's suggestion is a good one. Instead of a myList just keep a dictionary containing your other dictionaries with the name as the key. If you plan to search on other criteria then try a set perhaps

Comment: @Will so it would be something like: `myDict['John']`??

Comment: I'll post an answer to illustrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify `checkGuy` to something like:

```
def findGuy(dude_name):
   for d in myList: 
       if d['name'] == dude_name:
            return d
   else:
       return None # or use pass
```

And then do:

```
def addGuy(row_info):
     guy = findGuy(row_info[1])
     if guy is None:
         myList.append({'name':row_info[1],'code':row_info[0],'date':[row_info[2]]})
     else:
         guy.update(updated_dict)
```

Comment: Why return `i` instead of `d`?

Comment: @Barmar I think the dicts can easily be swapped, instead of updated

Comment: In this example I reduced the structure of the actual dictionary to get a clearer idea, but if I swap instead of update I might lose some variant information I need. Ex: multiple dates, where on each row there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer suggestion is pasted on the comments where it was suggested that if "name" is the only criteria to search on then it could be used as a key in a dictionary instead of using a list.

```
master = {"John" : {'code': 'code1', 'date': [123,456]}}

def addGuy(row_info):
    key = row_info[1]
    code = row_info[0]
    date = row_info[2]
    if master.get(key):
        master.get(key).update({"code": code, "date": date})
    else:
        master[key] = {"code": code, "date": date}
```

Comment: Why the down vote exactly? The answer was in response to request in the comments to illustrate an answer using a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: This is the same as just doing `master[key] = {"code": code, "date": date}`, update overwrite so it will end up the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you *dict.update* the existing data each time you see a repeated name, your code can be reduced to a dict of dicts right where you read the file. Calling update on existing dicts with the same keys is going to overwrite the values leaving you with the last occurrence so even if you had multiple "John" dicts they would all contain the exact same data by the end.

```
def read_file():
   results = {name: {"code": code, "date": date} 
                 for code, name, date in how_you_read_into_rows}
```

If you actually think that the values get appended somehow, you are wrong. If you wanted to do that you would need a very different approach. If you actually want to gather the dates and codes per user then use a *defauldict* appending the code,date pair to a list with the name as the key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
def read_file():
    for code, name, date in how_you_read_into_rows:
       d["name"].append([code, date])
```

Or some variation depending on what you want the final output to look like.